# Is there something similar to "ip tcp-metrics" available on Windows?

Tags: networking

The command `ip tcp_metrics` on Linux systems can be very helpful e.g. for analyzing historic network connections of the server without having access to log files. 
Is something similar to this command available on Windows based systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `netsh interface {ipv4|ipv6} show destinationcache` will do the job I was looking for, although there are not as many details available as in `ip tcp_metrics`.